# How to move an element after another has loaded

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I've got a fancybox modal/slideshow which is activated once you click on an item on the page.  It then creates a container div which is placed at the top of the body tag.

I want to nest this container div within the #content div on the page.  Tried to use the jQuery .appendTo method but it doesn't work.  I've assumed this is because I need to call this function after the fancybox container div has loaded.  This is where I got so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".fancybox-container").load($(this), function(){
    $('.fancybox-container').appendTo('#content');
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fancybox-container"></div>
    <section id="content">
      <a id="fancy-item" href="#"></a> <!-- When clicked this creates the fancybox container -->
   </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the selectors you are mentioning, I am assuming you are using fancybox v3.x. If that's true, then just use the `parentEl` API option in your call like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#fancy-item").fancybox({
        // API options
        parentEl: "#content"
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

That will nest the fancybox container inside the *section* with `content` ID

For fancybox v2.x, use `parent` instead.